# how can I split a list and print it in separate lines?

Tags: python, string, list, printing, split

Hi this is my code for Telegram bot,I have a list that fills by names.
the bot add usernames to list and reply it as a list
I want to reply every name in seperate lines

```
list = []
txt = str(list)


def msg_filter(bot , update):
wordsp = ["man"," miam"]
wordsn = ['nemiam','nistam','na']

if len(list) <=15:

    if any (i in update.message.text for i in wordsp):

        if "{}".format(update.message.from_user.first_name) not in list:
            list.append("{}".format(update.message.from_user.first_name))
            bot.send_message(chat_id = update.message.chat_id , text = "{}".format(list))
```

I have this in output : `['username1','username2','username3']`

but expect this:

```
[username
usernam2
username3]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to output the list new-line separated you can use [#join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and use the newline-character (`\n`) as separator for your list entries.

For example:

```py
bot.send_message(chat_id = update.message.chat_id , text = "\n".join(list))
```

which will output:

```
username1
username2
username3
```

If you explicitly want the `[` & `]` outputed as well, you can use format to add them:

```py
text = "[\n{}\n]".format("\n".join(list))
bot.send_message(chat_id = update.message.chat_id , text = text)
```

Answer (score 2):

you could use:

```
 print('\n'.join(list))
 # please do not name your list "list", list is a build-in function !!!
```

Answer (score 1):

text="[{}]".format("\n".join(lst))

Answer (score 1):

If you need exact this result without any quotes:

```
    [username1
    usernam2
    username3]
```

Try this simple solution:

```
    print(f'[{list_[0]}')
    for l in list_[1:-2]:
        print(l)
    print(f'{list_[-1]}]')
```

where list_ = ['username1','username2','username3']